# How custom action in android works?

Tags: android

public static final String ACTION_BATTERY_LOW = "android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"; this is a predefined string constant.But how this works ? means how   "android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" works....i mean if i register my broadcast reciever to respond to this how this can be done if this is just string? how system know that battery is low just through a string?? also i m exploring android.intent.action package but i could find it...suppose if i declare custom action like this String CUSTOM_ACTION="com.xyz.abc.CUSTOM_INTENT" then what does it mean ? which event will occur then this CUSTOM_ACTION will be called? kindly clearify my custom action in intent conecpt.What is custom action how i works and how a simple string can work?

Comment: The system will raise that intent URI when the battery is low.

Comment: can you please explain clearly i will be thankful to you